# vertical centered columns with headings flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

i managed to have vertically aligned column content with flexbox.
However, I need to have headers for the columns as well.

How can i have headers, in which the text is centered to the width of the column and which are at the top of the columns (the content must remain centered vertically)

see my codepen try:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNmrNx

```
.tothetop{
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      text-align:center;
      background: yellow;  
    }
```

put the headers on top, but the width does not match the column width so I can't center the text

Comment: So, you want `.wp:first-child` to be top aligned?

Comment: @Paul either that, or have an extra row for the headings, in which the columns have the same width as in the content row

Comment: Something like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONvoGw

Comment: @Paul perfect! flexbox is still new for me but it's amazing! :)

Comment: Actually, you did all the flexbox stuff, your final goal would not be possible with a simple flexbox setup. I just added a class and positioning.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want header text to be center horizontally in respect to columns. This may help you -

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}     
.myView {
            margin: auto;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: space-around;

            height: 500px;
            width: 500px;
        }

        .wpType {
           display: -webkit-flex;
           display: flex;
           -webkit-flex-direction: column;
           flex-direction: column;
           -webkit-align-items: center;
           align-items: center;
           -webkit-justify-content: center;
           justify-content: center;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
            border: 1px solid silver;
        }

        .wpType:nth-child(even){
            background: blue;
        }
        .wpType:nth-child(odd){
            background: red;
        }

        .wp{
            flex: 0 1 auto;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 10px;
            background: white;
            line-height: 100px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 2em;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="myView">
    <div class="wpType">
        <div class="wp"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="wpType">
        <div class="wp"></div>
        <div class="wp"></div>
        <div class="wp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpType">
        <div class="wp"></div>
        <div class="wp"></div>
        <div class="wp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wpType"><div class="wp"></div>
        <div class="wp"></div></div>
    <div class="wpType"><div class="wp"></div></div>

</div>
```